# How to auto populate country name in signup page using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Anyone tell me how to implement auto populate the country name in signup page. I am trying to get the location via IP and auto populate the country name without choosing country name in angularjs. 
My code in controller is,

```
 var country;
 $.get("http://ip-api.com/json/", function(response) {
 country=response.country;
 }, "jsonp");
```

Comment: Use `$http.jsonp` and assign response to scope as you would any other value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$.getJSON` instead of `$.get`

```
var country;
$.getJSON("http://ip-api.com/json/",
function(res) {
   country=res.country; 
});
```